# I stumbled upon problems with controll testing string in my Mastermind application

Tags: c#, console-application

well first of all I'm quite new to programing so please keep that in mind. I'm currently working on a MasterMind game, done in C# console application. I stumbled upon a problem while testing my diffrent methods. I wrote all test methods responds in the system.debug and the method that I've recived a fault from is the method "isValidKey(string key)"

I've got a "true" response form the "createSecretKey()"  and the MasterMind constructor;
So I assume they are fine.

So if you could please help me find whats wrong with the "isVaildKey(string key" method I would really appreciate it.

So here is my code:

namespace MasterMind
{

```
class MasterMindModel
{

    private string _secretKey;

    public MasterMindModel()
    {


        _secretKey = createSecretKey();

    }



    private static string createSecretKey()
    {
        string secretKey;
        string[] t_secretKey = new string[4];

        Random rnd = new Random();
        string symbols = "1234567";


        for (int i = 0; i <  4; i++)
        {
            char ch = symbols[rnd.Next(symbols.Length)];
            t_secretKey[i] += ch;

        }

        secretKey = t_secretKey[0] + t_secretKey [1] + t_secretKey[2] + t_secretKey[3];

        return secretKey;

    }


    public static bool SelfTest()
    {


        bool ok = true;

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000 && ok; ++i)
        {
            ok = isValidKey(createSecretKey());
        }

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("CreateSecretKey: " + ok);



        MasterMindModel model = new MasterMindModel();
        ok = isValidKey(model._secretKey);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("MasterMindModel constructor: " + ok);

        ok = isValidKey("2361") && !isValidKey("2368")
             && !isValidKey("ABCD") && !isValidKey("+-*=")
             && !isValidKey("2301") && !isValidKey("23611")
             && !isValidKey("231");
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("MasterMindModel isValidKey " + ok);

        return ok;
    }

    public static bool isValidKey(string key)
    {


        Random rnd = new Random();
        string symbols = "1234567";

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {

          char ch = symbols[rnd.Next(symbols.Length)];
          key += ch;

      }


        if (key != "2368" && key != "ABCD" && key != "+-*=" && key != "2301" && key !=   "23611" && key != "231")
        {
            key = t_key[0] + t_key[1] + t_key[2] + t_key[3];
        }


        return true;


    }
}
```

}
The compiler don't give me any errors and I can't seem too figure out what the problem is.

As I said I'm quite new, so any tips on what I should research and what syntaxes I should read more about etc. I would also apprieciate it.

Also please tell me if this post is to vauge and I will delete it and make another one. It's my first post here.

Thanks.

Comment: where is t_key defined?   key = t_key[0] + t_key[1] + t_key[2] + t_key[3];

Comment: Can you please explain in a bit more detail what you want the code to actually do as I am a bit confused by it.

Answer (score 0):

The immediate issue I see in your method is that t_key is not defined anywhere, can't explain why compiler isn't complaining unless you are not showing all the code.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing test cases in both SelfTest and isValidKey functions. You want to keep them in one place. Also you want to make your code more flexible by not using hard coded values so much. Also don't use static if not needed, you might want to run several instances of your model at once. Below is how I would do what you are trying to achieve:

```
class MasterMindModel
{
    private string createSecretKey(int keyLength, List<char> keyItems)
    {
        StringBuilder secretKey = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < keyLength; i++)
        {
            secretKey.Append(keyItems[_rnd.Next(keyItems.Count)]);
        }

        return secretKey.ToString();
    }


    private bool isValidKey(string key, int keyLength, List<char> keyItems)
    {
        if (key.Length != keyLength)
        {
            return false;
        }

        foreach (char c in key)
        {
            if (!keyItems.Contains(c))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    public void SelfTest()
    {
        int keyLength = 4;
        List<char> keyItems = new List<char> { '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7' };

        Debug.Assert(isValidKey(createSecretKey(keyLength, keyItems), keyLength, keyItems));
        Debug.Assert(isValidKey(createSecretKey(keyLength, keyItems), 3, keyItems) == false);
        Debug.Assert(isValidKey(createSecretKey(keyLength, keyItems), keyLength, new List<char> { '0', '8', '9' }) == false);
    }

    private static Random _rnd = new Random();
}
```